# can't display json data in my android app

Tags: android, json

i have make sharmuktakkhand .java file.

```
public class sharmuktakkhand extends AppCompatActiyvit {

    private final List<String> devices1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> deviceDescription1 = new ArrayList<>();
    public String[] devices;
    public String[] deviceDescription;
    public int pos;
    private ProgressDialog loading;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_geet);


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getData();
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    }
    private void showJSON(String response) {


        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(config.JSON_ARRAY);


            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(i);
                devices1.add(collegeData.getString(config.KEY_NAME));
                deviceDescription1.add(collegeData.getString(config.KEY_ADDRESS));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        for(int i =0;i<devices1.size();i++){

            Toast.makeText(sharmuktakkhand.this, devices1.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            devices[i] = devices1.get(i);
            deviceDescription[i] = deviceDescription1.get(i);
        }



    }

    private void getData() {
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(sharmuktakkhand.this, "Please wait...", "Fetching...", false, false);

        String url = config.DATA_URL;

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                loading.dismiss();

                showJSON(response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(sharmuktakkhand.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(sharmuktakkhand.this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            pos = position;


            bundle.putString(kavitaFragment.DevicesKey, devices[position]);
            bundle.putString(kavitaFragment.DescriptionKey, deviceDescription[position]);


            kavitaFragment deviceFragment = new kavitaFragment();
            deviceFragment.setArguments(bundle);


            return deviceFragment;
        }

        public void findposition(int posio ){

            Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("text/plain");
            i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My cool app");
            i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, devices[posio] + deviceDescription[posio] + "\nN.D.Nimbawat\nAdvocate");

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share"));

            return ;
        }
        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return  devices.length;
        }


        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            FragmentManager manager = ((Fragment) object).getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
            trans.remove((Fragment) object);
            trans.commit();

            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        }
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        SectionsPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        for(int i = 1; i<=devices.length ; i++) {
            adapter.addFragment(new kavitaFragment(), "shar muktak khand - "+ i );
        }
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                return true;

            case R.id.action_share:

                SectionsPagerAdapter mspa = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                mspa.findposition(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

and config.java file

```
public static final String DATA_URL = "http://m3microtech.com/getData.php";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "title";
public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "detail";
public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
```

i fetch data using JSON array and put this data in device1 (listArray)

problem is - fragment not create timely (fragment crate first then array using)

my app stop and not run.

please help me

thanks for advance

Comment: post your error reported on logcat.

Comment: Add your logcat error

Comment: Setup the viewpager and tab layout after getting data from server.

Comment: @Chandra check below answer.

Answer (score 0):

Dont setup `setupViewPager(viewPager);` if you dont have data wait for data then `setupViewPager(viewPager);`

Move `setupViewPager(viewPager);` to the response section of json as below.

```
private void showJSON(String response) {

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(config.JSON_ARRAY);

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(i);
            devices1.add(collegeData.getString(config.KEY_NAME));
            deviceDescription1.add(collegeData.getString(config.KEY_ADDRESS));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(int i =0;i<devices1.size();i++){

        Toast.makeText(sharmuktakkhand.this, devices1.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        devices[i] = devices1.get(i);
        deviceDescription[i] = deviceDescription1.get(i);
    }
  //  set here when your data is ready and also add check if data is null and show toast or your logic?
  setupViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

Comment: sir i change for your suggest but "unfortunately application has stop"

Comment: @ChandraPrakashPanwar this should be your structure set any adapter after getting data ....anyhow show your logs whats its saying now?

Comment: do you know about logcat or debug tools?

Comment: I am new developer and this is my first app. I can't understand logcat or debuging tools.

Comment: @ChandraPrakashPanwar no problem everyone starts like this ...me too one day you will be a expert.look if you send some to get some stuff for you he will go ...... and you are waiting he took ten 10 mint and you stay there if you go some where you can lose your stuff....... you waste resources your precious ten mints damm ..... cant you handle it in better ways.... you tell you boy when you get the stuff then tell so i will it from you and you can use your ten mints with your gf. so what you want to do?

Comment: its same thing we can use in coding ...... wait for response from web when repose cam back then set thing according to your response. Hope you understand.

Comment: i wait your response ...i have change all things you tell me but still response are some.